# Add new menu item in drop down admin menu

Tags: 6, routes

I have a node. I would like to create a link to the node in the administration menu. Adding an item in the administration menu is not working. Is this not possible? How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create more admin menu link from navigating to Management Menu, which you will find at this location -- **admin/structure/menu/manage/management**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a View to Admin Menu by setting the path on the page display under "page settings" for the View to admin/content/whatever-you-want and adding a "Normal menu entry" of whatever you want to call it. Admin menu will pick it up. But... if you try to add the same link through admin/build/menu it won't work. Cost me an hour to figure that one out... Might as well share it. lol.